Error "Jar URL 'spark-internal' is not in valid format" when creating Spark session via Livy in Hue (PySpark interpreter)
I am trying to create a PySpark session in Apache Hue using the following configuration for the PySpark interpreter:
[[[pyspark]]]
  name=PySpark
  interface=livy

While attempting to create the Spark session (before any job submission), I receive the following error:
Error
The Spark session is dead and could not be created in the cluster: Options: -c CORES, --cores CORES Number of cores to request (default: 1) -m MEMORY, --memory MEMORY Megabytes of memory to request (default: 1024) -s, --supervise Whether to restart the driver on failure (default: false) -v, --verbose Print more debugging output 24/10/03 21:43:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called 24/10/03 21:43:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-25eac57f-69d2-41f3-b7ad-f9e671fccd9f

Additionally, in the Livy session 0 logs, I see this error:
stdout

Jar url 'spark-internal' is not in valid format.
Must be a jar file path in URL format (e.g. hdfs://host:port/XX.jar, file:///XX.jar)

stderr

stderr: 
24/10/03 21:43:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Usage: DriverClient [options] launch <active-master> <jar-url> <main-class> [driver options]
Usage: DriverClient kill <active-master> <driver-id>

Options:
   -c CORES, --cores CORES        Number of cores to request (default: 1)
   -m MEMORY, --memory MEMORY     Megabytes of memory to request (default: 1024)
   -s, --supervise                Whether to restart the driver on failure
                                  (default: false)
   -v, --verbose                  Print more debugging output
     
24/10/03 21:43:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/10/03 21:43:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-25eac57f-69d2-41f3-b7ad-f9e671fccd9f

My setup:

Apache Spark in standalone mode.
Livy used to manage Spark sessions.
Hue with the PySpark interpreter configured to use Livy.
Running everything in Docker containers (Livy, Hue, Spark-master,
Spark-worker, etc.).
hue.ini https://pastebin.com/NsLq8pLB
livy.conf https://pastebin.com/HV34gSha
spark-defaults.conf (for both master and worker)
https://pastebin.com/QRSk0GDh
docker-compose.yml https://pastebin.com/41VaCjqJ

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Livy and Hue, especially in the context of Spark standalone in Docker? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
